# Dates ( pi-Day )

Tags: python, date

I think everyone kwows when it's pi-Day (If you don't know it's on 14 March each year). When you have a result in python like:

```
(2016, 4, 4)
```

(This stands for the April 4, 2016). How can I find in a fast way when it's the next pi-Day. In this example the answer would be:

```
(2017, 3, 14)
```

Is there any formula I can use? Many thanks!

Comment: `next_year = current_year + 1`?

Comment: `if (year, month, day) > (year, 3, 14): year += 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) you'd:

1. Get todays date
2. Get this years Pi-day (take the year from today's date)
3. If this date is in the past, add one year

In code:

```
from datetime import date

def next_pi_date():
    today = date.today()
    pi_date = date(today.year, 3, 14)
    if pi_date < today:
        pi_date = pi_date.replace(year=pi_date.year + 1)
    return pi_date
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> def next_pi_date():
...     today = date.today()
...     pi_date = date(today.year, 3, 14)
...     if pi_date < today:
...         pi_date = pi_date.replace(year=pi_date.year + 1)
...     return pi_date
... 
>>> next_pi_date()
datetime.date(2015, 3, 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

dates = [
    datetime.datetime(2014,2,4),
    datetime.datetime(2014,3,4),
    datetime.datetime(2014,3,27),
    datetime.datetime(2014,4,4),
    ]

for d in dates:
    if d.month < 3:
        print datetime.datetime(d.year, 3, 14)
    elif d.month == 3 and d.day <= 14:
        print datetime.datetime(d.year, 3, 14)
    else:
        print datetime.datetime(d.year+1, 3, 14)
```

Outputs:

```
2014-03-14 00:00:00
2014-03-14 00:00:00
2015-03-14 00:00:00
2015-03-14 00:00:00
```

This is checking that the month is less than 3 (March) and if it is, prints this year's Pi Day. If it is March, it makes sure it's less than the 14th. If it's after March, it uses next March 14th.